# importing github project into android studio

Tags: android, github

I set up git in Android Studio
http://maxrohde.com/2014/08/18/import-github-project-to-android-studio/

Then imported this project
https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR

The following error was displayed:

> Migrate Project to Gradle?
>   This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

That project hasn't been modified in two years, really four for most of the project, so it uses the older project layout and was very likely developed using Eclipse rather than Android Studio.

Here is the Google reference for migrating a project from Eclipse to Android Studio:
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

An option if simply importing doesn't work is to install Eclipse and do an export from there to Android Studio. While you could just work in Eclipse it is deprecated for Android development and you'll find many more up-to-date resources for Android Studio.
[How do you import an Eclipse project into Android Studio now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now)

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio's default build system is Gradle. That GiftHub project is not using Gradle build system. Probably created from Eclipse (Ant build system)

So when you open a project that does not use Gradle build in Android Studio, it will ask to convert the Project to Gradle based build. You just give yes on the popup, it will take care of everything.

Answer (score 0):

http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/#comment-184181

here it explains solutions for gradle errors

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error!
The recommended build system for android projects is gradle. 
But the author of this project in github did it using only eclipse without any special build system.

You just need to answer "yes" to that popup message and Android studio will convert the project to use gradle