# Importing Eclipse project to Android Studio not working

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am trying to fork [GCMHelloWorld](https://github.com/jmgjmg/GCMHelloWorld.git) from github. When I try to `Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)` using [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), I get an error saying `There are uncoverable errors which must be corrected first`. How do I import this Eclipse project in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

This answer here gives a very detailed step on how to do this with minimal problems https://stackoverflow.com/a/22791290/2864560

It should be worth noting that you would have to checkout your project to your computer, then use the actual Android Studio Wizard to import an Eclipse Android Project. Then you can sync it with your git repo (Even this might have a problem, so you may end up having to delete your old repo or renaming it and also making sure the new gradle scripts don't intermingle with the different Eclipse Hierarchy.