# How to load code from github into eclipse to load android app

Tags: eclipse, git

I need help in loading github code into eclipse.  I am wanting to recreate an android app. I am a beginner in coding and I am not sure where to begin.  A tutorial would be of great help.

Here is the link to the source code and I wanting to recreate.[enter link description here](https://github.com/deas/dslrdashboard)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is already answered in this post: [How do you import an Eclipse project into Android Studio now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now)

Just make sure to import from the root directory, otherwise the import will fail.

Comment: How would I choose the root directory?  I'm new to programming so I need step by step directions if you can help me

Comment: if you choose "Import Project" from the File menu or from the Welcome screen when you launch Android Studio, it should take you through a specialized wizard that will prompt you that it intends to copy the files into a new directory structure instead of importing them in-place, and it will offer to fix up some common things like converting dependencies into Maven-style includes and such.