# Import eclipse project to Android studio - error "this project refers to Eclipse workspace..."

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-import

I tried to import an existing project eclipse to Android Studio, but I got a dialog message in import that I can't solve : **"this project refers to Eclipse workspace relative path in its project metadata. To help import the project, please point to an Eclipse workspace directory."**

please check screenshots

[image]
[image]

How I can solve it?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: "Point to an Eclipse workspace directory" is pretty descriptive. Where on your hard drive are your Eclipse projects?

Comment: what if you don't have an eclipse workspace? The project could have been sent.

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: you can just delete the .idea and .settings folders from the project, and you can import it into studio after that

Comment: "Point to an Eclipse workspace directory" is pretty descriptive. Just put the path to the folder where the project you want to import is

Comment: There is .classpath hidden file in Eclipse project. can you put that in question?

Answer (score 15):

Simply delete all the folders and files from your project except manifest res,src and then import it in Android studio using  Import from eclipse

Comment: You save my day

Comment: If you never used Eclipse for Android development only this method seems to work.

Comment: Perfect Answer :) For mac fix, i Firstly install "Funter app for mac" to see hidden folder, after this i delete .classpath and .project and again recompile and magic is happens project is imported, i wasted many hours to import this project . but finally done with your suggestion, Thanx

Comment: @RamkeshYadav ... Your answer was a safe way to resolve this ! .... thanks

Answer (score 5):

I have same error. Let me explain all steps. You have Eclipse project and you want to import in Android Studio. So when you try to import it it will ask you to generate project at different location as shown below.

[image: Import Eclipse project]

when you click on next it will show you this screen.

[image: Replace all libraries]

after proceeding you will get this screen.

[image]

now the question is why it ask for Eclipse workspace path?

Answer: There is hidden `.classpath` file in your Eclipse project. the `.classpath` file contains information that the JDT feature needs in order to properly compile the project: the project's source folders (that is, what to compile); the output folders (where to compile to); and classpath entries (such as other projects in the workspace, arbitrary JAR files on the file system, and so forth).

First you have to select original Eclipse project path in Eclipse workspace path then you need to edit all file paths which is shown list. File names which are mentioned on left are already existed in original Eclipse project you have to set path so Android Studio will able to import project.

I have solved by this approach. Please let me know if you get any other error.

Comment: The key to my solution was the "hidden files". I didn't know that .classpath file was hidden! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.You can create new project in android studio and add all the files like java files in java folder and replace res files.If there is any library ,import those library as well.Now you are ready to work in android studio.

I have tried this when the same error occurs to me.

Answer (score 0):

For others who have the same problem,

Just remove `.classpath` file and then import the project again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

first you go to the place where your eclipse project is kept and delete the .classpath file.
then open your eclipse file with your android studio go to file-import project-Next-Next_finish

Answer (score -1):

First of all please make sure that you have done all steps in proper manner as provided here, [the migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) for projects in Eclipse/ADT

As you can see from migration guide the **Migration Prerequisites**

carefully see **In Eclipse ADT** section there they have already told this.

**It may be useful to record your workspace directory, path variables, and any actual path maps that could be used to specify any unresolved relative paths, path variables, and linked resource references. Android Studio allows you to manually specify any unresolved paths during the import process**

This answer have some best explaination of steps and the same question have other answers with pretty good picture representation.

since i have seen this same problem you have in [this specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34484133/5476209) the guy mentioned same problem and he tried again and successfully imported project. So you can Configure your build as [@AR.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38231608/5476209) mentioned in his answer. But i still want you to check that you have followed all steps perfectly because in most cases it shouldn't happen. You can try to browse your specific prject from your eclipse workspace and see whats happen.

Answer (score -1):

Try to export project from eclipse  or add module from  android studio. May be its takes your old dir paths. May be it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know the exact cause and criteria that causes this but, it has to do with External Libraries Studio does not recoginze. I have found a very hacky solution that has served my purpose. It is not a total solution but it is the best i can offer to gracefully allow importing all sources

1. Always back up your Data
2. In the eclipse project Remove all external libraries via  **project properties-> java build path**
3. Close the project and import into studio
4. Either Find compatible repo's with gradle or
5. add your previous external libraries .jar,.aar in the **libs** folder
6. point gradle to said folder and files
   **compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'mylib-*.jar')**

Like i said its a hacky work around but does the trick.