# Error while importing Eclipse project to Android Studio for support lib. v7

Tags: android, android-studio, import, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am new to android studio And I'm trying to import eclipse project in android with few dependent android projects.

Please see below attached image and my message console for the error.
I have tried by changing API version to 24 which is latest nothing happen and again back to API 21 after one answer on SO.
[image] 
Gradle version.
In wrapper I've 2.14.1 and in file I've 2.1.3

**build.gradle** file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package.name"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':comtwittersdkandroid_twitter')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.2.0'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/zxing-1.7-core.jar')
    compile files('libs/zxing-integration.jar')
}
```

I've tried adding jar instead of compile statement, it's not working.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: [Please check my answer here for the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38280020/4432725)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I finally break into the issue that is I have to **delete com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml** file from my project.
As I switch to API version 23 I removed http jars and added compile statements to build.gradle

**One Important** thing I've observed is "if you've dependent projects please cross check everything, as the main project mostly do not compile because of the issue with using same lib. in dependent projects or deprecated functions; as I have one for maps in one of my classes.

my **build.gradle** file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package-name"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/zxing-1.7-core.jar')
    compile files('libs/zxing-integration.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

Thanks for the help. Answer to help anybody who faces same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

you have a dependency with the support libraries **v24** which require api 24 to compile.
You have to use:

```
compileSdkVersion 24
```

Comment: Yes I have tried with API 24 as well. It is not working.

Comment: @AndriodNewbie what does "not working" mean? Post the error.

Comment: I've already added image for the type of error i'm getting. It's creating namespaces as seem in the image.