# Migrating Eclipse Project to Android Studio with dependencies

Tags: java, android, import, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

Imported an Eclipse Project to Android Studio having library dependencies of Sliding Menu, ViewPager, PullToRefresh. Import was successful but after syncing grade files getting duplication errors in values.xml.

```
~/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml
```

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you migrated your project in a standard way. You should use Android migration tools for this. Then, it will give you a summary of  changes and failures. So, you can spot your issue and find its solution. Make sure you keep the default setting in order to make a clean Android studio project. Please follow this post step by step and let me know if you still have issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36533889/5475941

I hope it helps.