# How to Import Project Made with Eclipse ADT into Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, eclipse-adt

I am working on a project that was made with Eclipse ADT.

I started up Android Studio, and clicked on "Import Project"

I am getting the following screen:

[image: screen]

I am currently unsure what to do, as the project was not made by me and as such I do not have access to the Eclipse workspace directory.

How should I approach this?

Comment: see my step by step answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Export from Eclipse

1. [Update your Eclipse ADT Plugin to 22.0 or higher](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html#Updating), then go to File | Export
2. Go to Android now then click on `Generate Gradle build files`, then it would generate gradle file for you.

   [image]
3. Select your project you want to export

   [image]
4. Click on finish now

   [image]

### Import into Android Studio

1. **In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see the Welcome to Android Studio window**.
2. Click Import Project.
3. Locate the project you exported from Eclipse, expand it, select it and click OK.

For more detail visit this : [How do you import an Eclipse project into Android Studio now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

1. In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see the Welcome to Android Studio window.
   2.Click Import Project(Eclipse,Gradle..etc)
   3.Choose The Project to import in Andriod Studio

Answer (score 0):

open android studio (assuming you already have one project open, else follow Kiruthika's answer ),
got to
1.file
2.new
3.import project
4.select your eclipse project
5.follow onscreen instructions