# Add Gradle to Android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am updating an application that was originally created in eclipse 
I imported it into android studio and edited the project strucutre and some how it worked
and I can now running the app & updating the code
the problem is its not gradle app I need it to be gradle for some module issues.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Android Studio you are using?

Comment: Android Studio v1.5.1

Comment: The newer versions of Android Studio(2.x) implicitly converts eclipse-adt projects into gradle based projects. Need to check for v1.5.1. Checkout this link if it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22797387/5460053

Comment: I guess it converts it too because the the link is about 2 years ago and the version is about a year :) anyway thanks a lot for your help