# Android appcompat v21 not work but v23 works

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-appcompat

i try using appcompat , and appcompat v23 works good but , support library version 23 have problems with something and i had to downgrad to older version!
when I using appcompat v21 as a library Eclipse error This :

> android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity Can Not Resolve

So i can't use Toolbar

how to fix it ?!
thanks

Comment: you most use AppCompatActivity

Comment: @darushdary my appcompat library not known in my project ( I add appcompat as a library too )

Comment: باشه . میشه کد هاتون رو نشنون بدید ؟

Comment: @darushdary bebinid proje man aslan appcompat ro be onvane ketabkhane Qabul nemikone yani aslan nemitunam tu code java importesh konam

Comment: باشه پس این کارار رو بکنید :

Comment: فایل build.gradle رو باز کنید

Comment: @darushdary rastesh tu eclipse kar mikonam va vaQti dakhele android studio import kardam build.gradle nadashtam tu proje

Comment: alan bulid.gradle ro dari ?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now) in link ro nega konid kareton rah miofteh

Comment: alan dorostesh mikonam age mishe begid tu gradle chi kar konam @darushdary

Comment: در ضمن راه راحت تر اینه که ابتدا یه پروژه تو اندروید استادیو بسازید بعد تمام فایل ها وکلاس هاتون رو واردش کنید

Comment: @darushdary kheyli mamnun

Answer (score 0):

این فایل برنامه خودمه میتونی کپی کنی

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

  dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'

}
```