# Adding Google Play Services Library to eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, email, google-play-services

So all we know that google sent us as devlopers an email telling us that we have to upgrade the  Google Play Services in order to ensure that ads keeps serving in our app and they shows in the email the way how we can upgrade in android studio
But i have some apps made by eclipse how can i upgrade to the latest update to ensure that the ads keeps working ?
i used to use Google Play Services version 4
Thank you

Comment: How did you do it the first time? I would repeat the same process

Comment: i just import the lib to my project in eclipse . but now i don't have the updated library

Comment: Android SDK enables you to download the latest Google libraries; so you should be able to do that in SDK Manager

Comment: Also seriously consider moving your project to Android Studio for future development

Comment: But in the firt i was able to find a folder named google-play-services_lib but now even when i updated the sdk i do not find it in the sdk folder

Comment: How much work will it take you to move to Android Studio? Because even doing it in Eclipse is a  temporary fix

Comment: yes but i have some apps in the store using the google ads . so have to make an update for each one to make sure that the ads keeps working after sept . and thank you for your answers

Comment: So you telling me that i can import the eclipse project to android studio ???

Comment: Of course, you can easily do that but of course you will need to switch to using Gradle dependency manager which is much easier

Comment: but how can i convert an eclipse project to gradle ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now

Comment: thank you  Eenvincible for your time

Comment: I hope you get it fixed; with Gradle, you will simply be changing the version number in one place and done with Google Play Services

Comment: I hope So Thank you again