# How to Migrate from eclipse to android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to migrate from eclipse to android studio,but my eclipse project content a library . how can i export this project as gradle to use it on android studio without lossing my library

Thank you

Comment: Check this one...
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects

Also check this link to migrate eclipse project to studio
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now

Answer (score 0):

**File > New > Import Project**

Go to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) official guide for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one...
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects

Also check this link to migrate eclipse project to studio
[How do you import an Eclipse project into Android Studio now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now)