# Genymotion error in Eclipse3

Tags: java, android, eclipse, genymotion

I am using Eclipse (last version, 64-bit) with Genymotion and SDK tools.

When I want to test my app in Genymotion, it shows me the following error with all my apps.

I use: run ass / Android app.

[image: 1]

Comment: Drop eclipse please.

Comment: Like @RobertEstivill said, drop eclipse. Here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now?answertab=active#tab-top and as for your problem, your image says error occurred during the build. I cant see much logs in the image. do you have any error logs?