# Want to shift to android stuio from eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Can anyone help me out with android studio.Actually I am making my android application in eclipse. But now I want to shift to android studio. But whenever i run my eclipse project in android studio. It oucers lots of errors. so i want to know the changes i have to do to run my eclipse project in android studio.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22797387/3111083.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read thoroughly on how to ask a question here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Migrate your sources to a IDE-agnostic build tool.

Answer (score 0):

if a project is open on Android Studio go to

> File > New > Import Project > Select the Eclipse project folder

if its first launch  click on

> Import Project (Eclipse , Adt) > Select the Eclipse Project Folder

Comment: But when we open the eclipse project. Lots of error occurred even after adding the dependencies.

Comment: can you share the error log

Comment: add google search, Andorid mainfest debug error, some of the dependencies are also not given like for common view pager,

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.designer.mehandic&hl=en                                                                                                                                                                  That's my app. I am making that type of app in an android studio.

Comment: update the question with  error log.   And you can manually make a eclipse project to a Android studio project by creating a new project with same package name and then simply pasting the SRC and RES folder in respective folders then sync the project.  And add the external libraries to gradle.

Comment: Thank you so much.