# Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.) option does not exit in Android Studio 2.3.2

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.) option does not exit in Android Studio 2.3.2. The only option that I can see is "Select directory with existing sources, Gradle build script(*.gradle).". 
[image]

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by turning on Android Support in Android Studio. In android studio go to File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Click on Android Support". Now Android studio will restart and you will have the import option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you import an Eclipse project into Android Studio now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now)

Answer (score 0):

Posting this incase someone else run's into similar issue.
I was able to resolve this issue by turning on Android Support in Android Studio. In android studio go to File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Click on Android Support". Now Android studio will restart and you will have the import option.