# How can I import an old Eclipse ADT Project in Android Studio 3.0.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, eclipse-adt

Until Android Studio 3.0.0 the menus were different and there was a seperate option to import from Eclipse ADT. With Version 3.0.1 this option disappeared.

How can I import my project to Android Studio 3.0.1 and base it on Gradle automatically?

The images can be found below. Because I need at least 10 reputation points I can't include them directly in this post.

[The initial Android Studio window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3OmD.jpg)

[After pressing import I choose my Eclipse ADT Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Zfz.jpg)

[Now I am stuck and confused on which to choose.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhNtG.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34484133/4517450

Comment: I can not confirm that with 3.0.1 the import option has been removed (Windows version).

Comment: The link does not help because it is outdated.

@Robert I am using Ubuntu and the import option is not removed, but it doesn't seem to work with Eclipse ADT anymore. 

In 3.0.0. there were different import options and especially one for Eclipse ADT projects.

Comment: @Sneh Pandya Nope.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange:

When starting "the new" Android Studio a redesigned "welcome screen" appears (see pictures in original post).

There is only an "Import project" button and after importing it, AS doesn't recognize the ADT Project Structure.

**Workaround/Solution:**

Open an existing Gradle Android project in Android Studio and close the project.

The old (and not redesigned) "welcome screen" pops up from where you can choose "Import project (Eclipse ADT)".