# import eclipse project in android studio from android manifest not working

Tags: android-studio

I tried to import an eclipse project into android studio it causes unresolved errors so after searching i found out that i should import android.manifest instead of gradle so when i tried to import it again it said cannot import project as shown bellow.

[image: The Project file specified already exists]

so my question is how can i remove existing project so i can import again ?

Comment: you can close project from "file-> close project" menu and re import your project

Comment: i already try this and it doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22791150/5928015

Comment: @ViperTecPro i want to do that but i can't do that because of the error shown in the description

Answer (score 0):

1. [Update your Eclipse ADT Plugin to 22.0 or higher](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt#Updating), then go to File |
   Export

[2. Go to Android now then click on Generate Gradle build files, then it would generate gradle file for you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laEfv.png)

[3. Select your project you want to export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmRbe.png)

[4. Click on the finish now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxH7i.png)

**Import into Android Studio**

1. In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see
   the Welcome to Android Studio window.
2. Click Import Project.
3. Locate the project you exported from Eclipse, expand it, select it
       and click OK.

Comment: this is the solution to migrate but my problem was that i couldn't import project as show in the description