# How do I make an android manifest for an existing non-android Eclipse project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have an existing project in Eclipse without the Android manifest, which i need in order to import it into Android Studio. How do I get that manifest?

Comment: Check this answer [Import Eclipse Project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37392626/10619147)

Comment: A properly formed  Eclipse project will have a Manifest (as all Android projects do regardless of build system).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: In Android Studio create new project and give it the same package name as has your project in Eclipse, for example com.example.myapplication, then copy AndroidManifest.xml to your Eclipse project then import it in Android Studio.

If something is missing you will have to add it in your AndroidManifest.xml