# How to import an eclipse project into android studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dependencies

I have a large major project with several sub projects in eclipse. Some sub projects have dependencies with major project.Now, I want to import these projects into Android Studio.I tried to export them use Eclipse and generate `build.gradle` files. After that, I use Android Studio to import them. But there are some problems.

> My sub projects can't find `.java` files in major project, so sub projects can't build successful.

So, what should I do to solve it? Forgive my poor English, thx.

> Update: I found that the sub project is also a `com.android.application` and it seems that a `com.android.application`(sub project) can't depends on other `com.android.application` (major project). What should I do?

Comment: Already answered here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now

Comment: What do you mean by "several sub projects", your major project needs some kind of project libraries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to import Eclipse project to Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485981/unable-to-import-eclipse-project-to-android-studio)

Comment: @taxo major project use jar files of sub projects, and sub projects use some class of major project