# "Please specify Android SDK" in Android Studio 0.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to run AVD/SDK manager from Android Studio. Each time the dialog pops up.

[image: AlertDialog]

It's strange because i'm already specified Android SDK.

[image: Android SDK selected]

Is there any another place where i should add Android SDK path ? Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I do not use Android studio, but suppose you need specify SDK in Modules scection

[image]

Comment: How can I get there? Modules doesn't come up for me under Project Structure.

Answer (score 29):

Simply perform these 3 steps

1. Open `gradle.buld` in your app module
2. Change `minSdkVersion` and sync gradle
3. Revert back your `minSdkVersion` and sync gradle again

Comment: Worked for me :)

Comment: I am from era of 2017, Still face this problem today with Android Studio 3.0 beta 2. And finally fixed with the solution @penguin provide.

Comment: woah. This happened to me after a power outage, probably corrupting some files. And this solution still works in 2017, Android Studio 3.0 beta 6

Answer (score 7):

For me, in the wake of a Windows Easy Transfer that didn't 100% work, the answer was to do the following, and the key step is in bold:

1. File->Close Project
2. Click "Configure"
3. Click "SDK Manager"
4. **Select the appropriate Android API, e.g., "Android 4.3 (API 18)" for the project**
5. While you're here, also select the appropriate Android SDK Build-tools, e.g., 18.1.1
6. Click "Install packages..."
7. Close out and reopen your project, and you should have no problem accessing the SDK Manager via Tools->Android->SDK Manager

Note: You can determine which versions of the Android SDK and SDK Build-tools you need by inspecting your build.gradle file.  In my case, I had the following lines:

```
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"
```

My experience is somewhat peculiar, because I recently migrated from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 using **Windows Easy Transfer**.  When I did this, my local git repository and some of my Android Studio settings transferred over, but apparently not everything.  When I installed Android Studio on the new machine, I set my ANDROID_HOME environment variable, then opened Android Studio, and it immediately put me in the project I had most recently opened on the **old** machine.  My fresh install of Android Studio didn't include the Android 4.3 SDK, and it seems that jumping straight into the project threw SDK Manager for a loop.

Prior to performing the above sequence of steps, I confirmed that my ANDROID_HOME was correctly set.  I also tried setting the project default SDK, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18409923/315702.  AND I tried setting the SDK within the Project Structure of the project that was giving me trouble.  None of these things fixed my particular problem.

Comment: I've tried different things as well and that's the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed the issue by setting correct android sdk
Android Studio->project structure->Modules(app)->properties tab-> set the correct SDK

Answer (score 4):

You can simply tap **Sync Gradle**

[image]

Nice and Clean !!!

Answer (score 3):

For me, what did the trick was changing the compileSdkVersion 19 to compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:19" so it uses the Google API platform instead of just the 19 platform.

Comment: FWIW: For me it was the opposite. I had to change 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:14' to just 14. I guess it depends on what your sdks folder says. I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project and select `Project Structure`, on left hand select sdks and in right panel browse your `sdk` from sdk folder like (`adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030` folder for Windows)

Answer (score 1):

For me even simpler steps worked:

1. Open buld.gradle in app module
2. Add a space or newline on any line's
   end
3. Sync gradle

Note I am on Android Studio 2.x , but solution should hold for earlier versions of android studio as well

Answer (score 0):

My environment is not exactly same as yours. I am using Android Studio 0.5.2 (android-studio-bundle-130.737825-windows.exe). I also met the "Please specify the Android SDK" message as your screenshot.

After some investigation, I notice the "SDK Manager" binary was missing in the Android Studio. Then I installed adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917.zip. In Android Studio - File - Project Structure - Android SDK - Android SDK location, fill in the folder for adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk. And everything was OK.