# Android Studio updates have led to errors

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

I just updated my Android Studio to the current 0.3.1 version. Consequently I've started getting a few issues that I can't seem to understand. First I get this message about problems with the plugin on launching Android Studio. The message is as follows:

```
Plugin Error
Problems found loading plugins: Plugin "Android Designer" was not loaded: 
required plugin "Android Support" is disabled. 
Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: 
required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.  
Disable not loaded plugins Enable Android Support Open plugin manager
```

The most worrying - which has essentially halted my progress at the moment - is that the IDE can't resolve XML files in the R.xxx. Such as this line:

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_lists);
```

It suggests I use android.R which brings up further errors due to incompatibility. I'm not sure how to fix this. On another occassion when this happened, further updates automatically resolved this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Android SDK Manager, select the following items and then click Install packages:

Extras/Google Repository

Extras/Android Support Repository

After install restart Android studio

Comment: Thanks that seems to work but now it mentions that the SDK is not specified. I try to open Project Structure but all I get is this: 

4:23:22 PM Throwable: module editors was not disposed

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-change-android-sdk-path

Answer (score 1):

I try  to remove and  reinstall  Extras  but  the problem  is not solved , I find a solution to correct  that to  reset AndoidStudio.

You  have to remove  this  directory and restart AndroidStudio to detect the SDK location

```
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
```