# Error Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded Android studio v 1.1.0

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

Hi i created an cordova app in iOS and it is working fine now i want to build app in android i gave command in terminal

```
Cordova platform add android
Cordova build android
```

Now i downloaded Android device manager sdks selected api 19 and   android studio v1.1.0

when i import project it gives this error.

```
Plugin Error
Problems found loading plugins: Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
```

this link didn't solved my problem
[Android Studio updates have led to errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681234/android-studio-updates-have-led-to-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Click the menu "**File**" - "**Settings**" - "**Plugins**" to see "**Android Support**" is unchecked.

At this point, follow the steps below, first uncheck "**Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio**", and then check the "**Android Support**", click "**Apply**" button and then click "**OK**" button,

Android Studio will prompt to restart, restart Android Studio , And then returned to normal.