# Plugin Error after updating Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1, android-studio-plugin

I dont know why this plugin errors occurred but after updating **Android Studio 2.1** I am getting this every time after starts **Android Studio**

[image]

Anyone know about it? Any Solution?

Comment: Can u check in settings->Plugins those plugins enabled or not(Checked)?

Comment: @Raghavendra Yes, All plugins are checked.

Comment: I guess you have already seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681234/android-studio-updates-have-led-to-errors)

Comment: @Raghavendra Ya but its totaly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check all plugins are installed or not that for Go To **`File > Setting > Plugins`**

See below image and proper install or update Android studio plugins.

In your case some of plugins disable that for get error, Enable all plugins. That for **Check/Uncheck** Some plugins and **Apply/Ok**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Its just like **check/uncheck** Some plugins and Apply/Ok. Restart *Android Studio* and Working fine..