# Android Studio renaming module

Tags: android, android-studio

After renaming module in Android Studio i get error `Project SDK is not defined`.

How can I rename module from **app** to **my-name** whit out getting error.

The problem is with renaming, I believe.

I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to rename the module. If I rename the directory I get this error. If I rename module, after restart there are no previous changes. the problem is not in setting SDK, the problem is that classes are no longer in package. The AS doesn't know that this module is android app because there is also previously created

Comment: this is the error that I get. The problem is with renaming, I believe. shift + alt + R to rename the module. If I rename the directory I get this error. If I rename module, after restart there are no previous changes.

Comment: No, I'm saying, why don't you just define your SDK?

Comment: its not problem in SDK. I edited post. please check.

Comment: If it's not an issue with the SDK, why did you get that error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To raname a module, go to settings.gradle and rename the module to your new name. Then close Android Studio, and rename the folder using File Explorer. Now reopen Android studio and your module name will be updated.

Simply renaming using the refactor tool does not do the job.

Comment: Re-starting Android Studio is not necessary - it is enough to call Build -> Clean Project

Comment: radistao, your correct! I was just pointing out that you should rename it in Finder or whatever the file explorer is for your PC. jsanmarb, i don't understand what you mean, does the above not work for you?

Comment: This is late 2017 and in my experience renaming modules using the IDE now works more or less flawlessly. You might need to manually update settings.gradle if that renamed module is included in other projects, or perform a project clean, but other than that, it works.

Comment: In my experience it fails to change the package name in the renamed modules `AndroidManifest.xml`. Just changing it manually works.

Comment: Need also to change  the path in gradle file:  implementation project(path: ':newName')

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the command for compiling is the same, and when the program tries to do compilation the unchanged name is passed in instead of the new name.

See [Android Studio - How to Change Android SDK Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path)

File->Project Structure->SDK(under Platform Settings)->Android SDK