# Gradle execution fails without stating the cause

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a big problem with the Android Studio on my Win 8.1 (32-bit) 
when I finish my app (everything is correct. No Bugs).

I can't try it on emulator or generate a registered APK, and I get this error:

```
Failed to complete Gradle execution

Cause:
```

(there is no cause just an empty line)

also I can't open the SDK Manager :(

Comment: msgs tab:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:C:\Users\Ayham\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\Ayham\AndroidStudioProjects\Firstlesson\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.2-492c833ed7692533ed7aa043d989bf322215f185.jar C:\Users\Ayham\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\21.0.2\support-annotations-21.0.2.jar
Error Code:1
Output:The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It helped me, FINALLY !!!

*close android studio
    *Download http://goo.gl/v0UPm6
    * goto \sdk
    * rename 'tools' to 'tools1' (In case you need backup)
    * extract this zip to \sdk
    * it will make tools folder in \sdk
    *restart studio and errors will be gone

Source: [Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/107852486976928213243/posts/eASLDXpavAX)

PD: Thank you, Aman ;)
PD2: Android SDK Tools 24.0.1 is coming !!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Settings -> Gradle

Input the following in the "Gradle VM options:" box: -XX:MaxHeapSize=256m -Xmx256m

Hit apply and Android Studio should build your project successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your **SDK** is not on the path that it is expected to be **or** inside your Android Studio you have to specify the path to where you have your SDK on your computer.

Comment: ok then, how can I change the path, the SDK manager is not working :(

Comment: YOu might find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path  or by googling it. I'm sure there are solutions online for this fix.

Comment: nop >> I put the right path but nothing changed, the same problem, and I googled a lot for this :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to double check your SDK and it's path, that's usually the case.

Comment: ok I think I will repeat every thing, can you please send me a link for the correct SDK package for the android studio?

Comment: I used http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html and it woked fine but if it doesnt you can check http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html hope it helpt.