# unable to create new project in Android Studio

Tags: android, import, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and I can't create or import any project. When I tried to import a new project, it show error like:

```
Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
Required by:
    Telegram-master:TMessagesProj:unspecified

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the packages with **Android SDK Manager** for the version of android you are going to develop.

See [HERE](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html) and [HERE](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html) how to do it.

See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path) answer to change SDK path if you need to.

Good luck!

Comment: i had already installed it using eclipse at its work fine but in android studio i cant import it

Comment: try installing older versions too if the project needs to be backward compatible. I had the same problem.

Comment: And i also cant see the sdk manager in tools menu i cant find what is the the problem

Comment: is thr any tool lik adt as eclipse

Comment: Not sure about the tools menum you probably set the path to SDK wrong and first start of the studio, but I just went to installation folder and started it from there. Restart the studio and there is a way to change the path in the first dialog.

Comment: @user3634291 check the answer I found instructions how to change SDK path

Comment: i tried to restart thro installation folder but it dsnt ask sdk path how to set it manualy