# Install/Run multiple Java for Java Web Start and Android

Tags: java, android, virtual, java-7, jdk6

I am using Windows 7 64bit OS with 4GB RAM. I installed Java 6.70 in my PC for running a very specific application in Java Web Start. I want to install the latest Android Studio v1.0+ (for Lollipop Sideproject), which requires JDK 7+.
I tried to install both in different order. But, It always takes the latest version as JAVA_HOME. So, my Web Start app wont run.

One possibility is Virtual machines running Android. But when tried with ubuntu14 + android is heavy for my PC. Or is there a less footprint VM config available?

Or, Is there any other way to run Android Studio with JDK7 isolated from the Java 6, as I don't want to break the current application?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing SDK location in Android Studio? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path