# Is it possible to download the android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip for android studio separately and just unzip in the folder where it should be

Tags: android, android-studio

My college wifi is preventing me from downloading of large files unless i use some online proxy servers. So will it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Download it and unzip it in any folder and then use it in android studio.

See this link for setup path [Android Studio - How to Change Android SDK Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path)