# Android SDK gives wrong path, Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, appdata

Recently I've started to get involved in Android developing, and I learned that Android Studio was available contrary to Eclipse. So I downloaded the new software by Google and started it up. It prompted me to install some SDK packages and I did all that it recommended me to do at

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Then I saw a link that said you can find out where your SDK path is by opening the SDK manager up top, as well as the answer described on this page

[Android Studio - How to Change Android SDK Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path)

So I copied the path and tried to use the run command (I can't post images yet) The path is described as 
C:\Users\baruy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

I get an error saying that it doesn't exist. I browse for the files by myself, to learn that there is no AppData folder under baruy

Windows 8 64-bit, home edition. Please help, thanks

Comment: So, let me see if i get this straight. You used the run command to run a folder path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppData is a hidden folder on windows. In order to show hidden files and folders on windows 8, follow [this guide on msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zxue/archive/2012/03/08/win8-howto-19-show-hidden-files-folders-and-drives.aspx).

In short, you should go to Control panel->Folder options->"View" tab and then check the "Show hidden files, folders and drives". If you don't find the android sdk after that than it is simply not there.

Answer (score 0):

AppData is an hidden folder. Paste that path in the window manager path and you should get there. Alternatively use the console and type:

```
cd AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Android 3.0 this path error came up. The default Sdk path in mac is /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk, and as that was marked in the systems settings the studio just had to be restarted and it worked again.