# How to set a running device with android studio?

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile

I want to connect an android device to test my application directly from my environment android studio

android studio - http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

I have a samsung galaxy s5 device, I've connected it to usb, I've installed this drivers:

http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117

and there are said that:

```
The USB Driver for Windows is available for download in this page. You need the driver only if you are developing on Windows and want to connect a Samsung android device to your development environment over USB.
```

so, in my windows 7 device mananger I see that in the section "portable devices" the phone is listed, and its name is identified, but in the android studio when I run my application, then I should select if a want to run it with a virtual or real device, so in the list of running devices in android studio, my device is not listed, I 've tried to restart the pc, but no results, can anyone tell me what I'am doing wrong? I can't understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Android Studio, you have to setup Android SDK to your Windows and make ADB work everywhere. However, now life is a lot easier when you use Android Studio since everything includes in it, you just need to enable USB Debugging on your phone and Run.

Follow this link: [Run on a Real Device](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice)

You still doesn't work, try to follow step by step on that page.

Comment: I've tried to set the phone to debug mode, but it still not in the list of running devices, yes I think android studio includes android sdk isn't?

Comment: It does include SDK on OS X but I am not sure for Windows. Try to find where is the SDK locate and go into folder "platform-tools". You will see adb or adb.exe from there if everything corrects. If you cannot find adb, try install it separately instead, after you can connect ADB to your phone, tell Android Studio to link SDK from here. Next, open command line and go to that folder to run "adb devices" or "adb.exe devices", you should see your phone on the list. If your device not appear, try to open USB Debugging or other devices, it must be something else wrong.

Comment: oh finally, i though that debug mode is on when I tap 7 times the build number, I found the checkbox "enable debug mode", and it worked thank you a lot :D

Comment: Here is where to get and set SDK path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the drivers are not compatible. Try installing the drivers that come with android sdk.

To install the Android USB driver on Windows 7 for the first time:

1. Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
2. Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and
   select Manage.
3. Select Devices in the left pane. Locate and expand Other device in
   the right pane.
4. Right-click the device name (such as Nexus S) and select Update
   Driver Software.This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
5. Select Browse my computer for driver software and click Next.
6. Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB
   Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
7. Click Next to install the driver.

Or, to upgrade an existing Android USB driver on Windows 7 with the new driver:

1. Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
2. Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and
   select Manage.
3. Select Device Manager in the left pane of the Computer Management
   window.
4. Locate and expand Android Phone in the right pane.
5. Right-click Android Composite ADB Interface and select Update
   Driver. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
6. Select Install from a list or specific location and click Next.
7. Select Search for the best driver in these locations; un-check
   Search removable media; and check Include this location in the
   search.
8. Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB
   Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
9. Click Next to upgrade the driver.