# Are files in Android SDK Platforms folder on Windows and Linux the Same

Tags: android, linux, windows

Are the files in Android SDK platforms folder on Windows the same as the one in Linux? I just want be sure than to download files I have already on my computer.

Comment: do u refer to all the files???? or if the paths to those files are the same?

Comment: I mean the  files. updated my question.

Comment: Then they are not the same by the sizes info!!

Answer (score 1):

It´ll sure not be the same.  Check this answer they explain how to check it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16582792/3617531

**EDIT**

As you were asking for the files, just check this url. You will see the sizes are not the same between linux and windows, then, I recommend  you to download them again.. and make it a fresh install...
https://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html

Comment: Also... I´m not pretty sure if your linux android will read correctly the windows one files or viceversa.... due to file formats