# Unable to change SDK path in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I am unable to change the **ANDROID SDK** path in **Android STUDIO IDE** .
 Even after changing path it still reflecting in the default path **C:\/Appdata\Local/Android\sdk**

My question is, Is it possible to change the native **Android_SDK** path in **STUDIO IDE** in windows machine ?

Comment: Yes, of course you can change path in Windows machine.

Comment: @Abhishek Please can you share me the instructions to solve my problem.

Comment: can you tell me the approach you used to change the sdk path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Preferences**[image]

Then Go to **SDK** option [image]

Then Choose the **location of your sdk** folder[image]

This Screenshots are from my Mac. The similar process you can follow for your Windows Device.

Comment: No such menu item named "Preferences" in my Android Studio, instead it's labeled as "Project Structure".

Comment: Which OS r u using  ??

Comment: Go to local properties and change the sdk path

Answer (score 0):

**Changes Android SDK Location in Windows OS**

1. Click on File > Project Structure

[image: Project Structure under File]

2. Change the Android SDK Location.

[image: Android SDK change location path in windows]