# How to change Android SDK Manager file path

Tags: android, filepath, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I have serious disk size limitations (~64GB) so I need the Android SDK to be installed on another disk. I already changed the file path for the installation of Android Studio and Android SDK. But when I start the Android SDK Manager it says the SDK Path is on the small disk (default OS disk) in the AppData: "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk".
[image]

How can I change this?
[One answer suggests changing it from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path) But the file paths in there are correct.
[image]

Comment: Manually move your SDK to another disk and run the update manger there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio - How to Change Android SDK Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path)

Comment: @user4847410 Nope, I mentioned that, those paths are correct. But apparently I was starting another installation of the Android SDK in another location.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I to got same problem but if you open sdk manager at new location of your path ,it is all set and also it is easy to use sdk manager in Android studio itself.
You can also use eclipse to launch the new sdk manager by setting the path.