# How can connect Eclipse Android SDK manager in Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am studying Android and I am having a little problem. My mistake is I used eclipse to install/download some of the Android SDK. And I want to move to Android Studio but how can I use my downloaded android sdk in Eclipse?

Comment: this is what you looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path

Comment: android studio would automatically detect the existing sdk from your machine I guess or will ask you to locate the sdk. If it does not work, go to file->Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK and then change it to your desired location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the downloaded sdk folder path here: File->Settings->Android SDK(in left side of the window)-> Android SDK location(in top of window)