# Android studio only finding "some" classes when browsing SDK sources

Tags: java, android-studio

I seem to be having a massive problem with paths when browsing the SDK sources. Basically my issue is this:

I can import (for example) android.annotation.NonNull into my own project and it recognises the class fine. But if I open Activity.java I get random classes not being able to be found - but they exist in the correct path. For example it can find android.os.PersistableBundle (which exists at androidSDK\sources\android-23\android\os\PersistableBundle.java), but not android.annotation.NonNull (which exists at androidSDK\sources\android-23\android\annotation\NonNull.java)

I have tried invalidating caches and restarting, re-installing android studio, installing different versions and even redownloading the whole SDK, but nothing is making it happy. Is there a place I should be setting the 'root' path? How come it finds some classes but not others?

Comment: Welcome to Android Studio Hell!! Everytime this happens to me I refresh the project, some times change something on the problematic clas (like add a space somewhere and delete) then save the class again solves it. But not everytime. In other times I end up reseting the android studio location. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18409923/460557

Answer (score 0):

Android 1.2 or idea 14 do not have this problem. After this version have this problem.
You can view thie SDK source by use the Android 1.2. [Click here to download](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/1-2-1-1). Unfortunately, Android 1.2 version has some other bug.