# Android Studio setup JDK error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jdk1.8-73

In Android Studio I am facing bellow error 
[image]

This popup shows when I press `Alt+Enter` for missing classes(symbols). When I click on setup SDK it shows two options

1. 1.8(Java version "1.8.0_60")
2. Android API 23 Platform (Java version "1.8.0_60")

Nothing happens on selecting any of above options.

**NOTE:** My Java_Home path is correct and in android studio I have checked JDK path it's correct.

I am using Android Studio 1.5.0, Java 1.8 and windows 10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Comment: @Android Plz read my question my Java path is correct then why should I change it ?

Comment: Downvoters add reson of down vote in comment

Comment: Have you tried File--> Invalidate Cache and Restart ?

Comment: Android Studio 1.5 is basically deprecated. Is there a reason why you can not use Android Studio 2.3 or higher? Since Android Studio 2.2, a JDK is already bundled inside of Android Studio, and you will not run into this issue any longer.

Comment: @JamalEason it's an old post, now I am using Android Studio 2.3

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simple `Invalidate Cache and Restart` doesn't work for me. So I have done following steps:

1. Check and verify Java path in Java_home variable
2. Start Android Studio and invalidate cache `File--> Invalidate Cache and Restart`

Comment: Worked with Android studio 3.3

Comment: i dont think the first step is necessary; i had the same problem(my java version was 1.8 too) and doing just the last two steps worked. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 15):

Start Android Studio and click **File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart.**
This has worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well... In my case, setting up JDK in `Project Structure` didn't work. `Invalidating and restart` didn't work either. On further debugging, it led me to this:
[Can-t-start-Intellij-after-update](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000536364-Can-t-start-Intellij-after-update)
Background of this problem:
I had installed Android Studio 3.6 and upgraded to Android Studio 4. Plugins like `Mateial theme`, `Flutter`, `CSV viewer`, `JSON viewer` etc weren't compatible with Android Studio 4. So I had disregarded those plugins after I upgraded to AS 4.
After some days, I got a notification that plugins which I had disregarded earlier were compatible with AS 4. So I installed those and restarted AS 4 and applied `Material theme`. I started to face problems like `Set up JDK` even though the path to JDK was proper.
So I closed AS 4, deleted caches from `.gradle`, `.android`, `.AndroidStudio4.0\system\caches`. Then I opened AS 4 and `set up JDK` error was gone.
Hope it helps...
P.S: If same problem persists, then I'm afraid that you've to unistall AS and download AS 4 directly and install it. I still can't figure out why it happened to me...

Answer (score 1):

Close Android studio then again open it .
Go to File--> Invalidate Cache and Restart .
You are done.