# Where is adb.exe in windows 10 located?

Tags: android-studio, adb, windows-10

I installed android studio 1.5 on windows 10.

When I type in command line:

> adb

I get command not found.

Where can I get it from or where is it installed?

Comment: Different question but gets you the path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path

Comment: A Windows Explorer search doesn't find it for you?

Comment: a trick I used was to launch task manager and there see location of adb, when running

Answer (score 528, accepted):

It is located in the `AppData` hidden folder

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

From l33t's comment below you may use the following shortcut:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

> To use it in PowerShell you can do: `$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Android\sdk\platform-tools`

Comment: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Comment: My path was slightly different: `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe`

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

Comment: `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\`

Comment: `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`

Comment: for me it was `C:\android-sdk-windows`

Comment: For me, it's `C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools`. Regardless of what it is on your machine, you shouldn't need to deal with any hidden folders.

Answer (score 58):

You can find it here:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

To save yourself the hassle in the future, add it to your path:

1. Click 'Start'.
2. Type 'Edit environment variables for your account', and click it.
3. Double click `PATH`.
4. Click 'New'.
5. Paste that path in.
6. Click 'OK', click 'OK', and restart any command prompts you have open.

Comment: This works. You will have to restart Android Studio to see the changes in Terminal.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio it's C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

Comment: @NickTurner You should post that as a new answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the steps are not clear. What is Path in step 3?

Comment: @William The `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 32):

- Open android studio

[image]

- Press configure or if project opens go to settings 
  [image]
- lookup Android SDK shown in picture
  [image]
- You can see your Android SDK Location. Open file in file explorer to that location.
- Add this to end or direct through to this

> \platform-tools\adb.exe

full path on my pc is :

> C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Answer (score 10):

### Steps to add `adb.exe` to environment variables for global access

- Run the following on Windows Run (Win + R)

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

- Copy the path to the folder from the address bar
- Then, search for `Environment Variables` on the windows search bar
- Click on `Environment Variables`
- Under `System Variables` select the `Path` environment variable & click on `Edit`
- If the `Path` environment variable does not exist, create a new one by clicking on `New`
- A new window appears - in the new window, click on `New`
- Then paste the path to `adb.exe`
- Click `OK` (thrice!)

You can now access the commands like `adb`, `sqlite3` etc globally from Windows

Answer (score 8):

If you are not able to find platform-tools folder, please open SDK Manager and install "Android SDK Platform-Tools" from SDK Tools tab.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

I have taken snapshot of adb.exe directory. I hope it helps you best,

Answer (score 7):

Open a `cmd` window and type `where adb.exe`

For me

`D:\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe`

Answer (score 5):

You'll find it in the `AppData` folder if you choose to install it in the default location. Otherwise, it will be located at the folder where you installed your Android SDK/`platform-tools` folder.

Answer (score 4):

I know the question was in the context of "android studio 1.5", but I found this answer and have Xamarin installed.

In this case, the location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`

Comment: Yes, mine was located here, and not in AppData

Answer (score 4):

You can look in C:\android\sdk\platform-tools . This was where I found it on my computer.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to run `adb` command. Open command prompt and run following command:

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb devices
```

**NOTE: Make sure to replace <user_name> in above command.**

Comment: You could replace 'C:\Users\<user_name>' with '%HOMEPATH%'.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work go to the *local.properties* file under your **build.gradle** files to find out the PATH to your **SDK**, from the **SDK** location go into the *platform-tools* folder and look and see if you have *adb.exe*.

If not go to http://adbshell.com/downloads and download **ADB KITS**. Copy the zip folder's contents into the platform-tools folder and re-make your project.

I didn't need to update the PATH in the Extended Controls Settings section on the emulator, I left *Use detected ADB location* settings on. Hope this makes this faster for you !

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have Android Studio installed, and require the environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` to be set, the easy way to do this is to add `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools` to your path.

Comment: %ANDROID_HOME% is where Android Studio was installed, which is different from the path where (I do not understand WTH) the tools are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was in: 
C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools

Comment: This was probably a custom install, for some reason or another.

Answer (score 0):

if you know SDK'path on your system, 
(by default, it's in  /users/appdata/local/Android/...

then, open platform-tools or platform/platform-tools and  launch cmd...

it's there you can  write *adb*