# App got crashed when tried to open a generator

Tags: java, android

I tried to build a scanner and generator in 1 app. When I press the generator button, It suddenly crash. I don't have any error or warning in my log.

**Here's my generator code:**

```
public class GeneratorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText text;
Button gen_btn;
ImageView image;
String text2Qr;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_generator);
    text = findViewById(R.id.text);
    gen_btn = findViewById(R.id.gen_btn);
    image = findViewById(R.id.image);
    gen_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            text2Qr = text.getText().toString().trim();
            MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
            try{
                BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(text2Qr, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,200,200);
                BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            catch (WriterException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

**MainActivity code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button gen, scan;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gen = findViewById(R.id.gen);
    scan = findViewById(R.id.scan);
    gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent gIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GeneratorActivity.class);
            startActivity(gIntent);
        }
    });
    scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent rIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReaderActivity.class);
            startActivity(rIntent);
        }
    });
}}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? Please help me.

UPDATE

Here's my xml code for the generator:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="415dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:hint="@string/enter_text_to_generate"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gen_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="@string/generate"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text" />

<view
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="293dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="188dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this will help my issue :(

UPDATED: This is fix by stupid typo from me ;). Thank you so much for everyone that replied to my question this far. I can't say much how grateful I am. Especially for the guy that I already vote for the right answer. You're truly a hero!

Comment: Remove all filters from logcat and check it again. If your app crashes, there is a log somewhere...

Comment: @EduardoHerzer how to remove a filter from logcat? is it clean project? sorry for stupid question, i'm newbie.

Comment: @RicardoF.Seikka post your error..

Comment: @EduardoHerzer that's the thing. In my log, I don't have any errors and warnings but when I'm done install it from the apk, it just crash when I want to open the generator app part.

Comment: @RicardoF.Seikka ok fine...did tested some other mobile...try to create build apk run it oncd let me know

Comment: @GowthamanM I need to make sure that It can run on my mobile cause I need to present it within my mobile. And I don't really have any other mobile.

Comment: @RicardoF.Seikka this link has info how to change filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19948588/2174489

Comment: @Ricardo F. Seikka may sound weird, What is the OS(Windows/Mac/other) you working on (your computer) ??

Comment: @RicardoF.Seikka yes,,,, keep NoFilter  check  what exception you are getting then post it stack..so that people can help you

Comment: Already put 'no filters' on it, still got crashed. My scanner is fine, only the generator when I tried to open it in my app.

Comment: Have you declared `GeneratorActivity` in the manifest file?

Comment: @EduardoHerzer already did in my AndroidManifest

Comment: `GeneratorActivity` opens and it crashes when you click on a button inside it? Post full code from `GeneratorActivity`

Comment: @EduardoHerzer I already post the full code for the generator? are you asking with the xml too or?

Comment: @RicardoF.Seikka yes please

Comment: @EduardoHerzer done sir. Please check it

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit difficult without the error. Try to check what @tannitanna wrote above as answer and post the error log...

Comment: @RicardoF.Seikka check my answer... I guess you just made a typo in the component name

Comment: @EduardoHerzer Hello sir. Thank you for yesteryday at solving my stupid case. I still have 2 problems that really need to be done, but I don't really know how to solve it. I can't ask another questions in this site cause already on my limit to ask it. Can you help me please? I really need this project to be done soon :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I got your problem! (If it isn't a typo in the question...)

At your xml you declared a component named `view`, when the correct is `View` with an uppercase:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: Oh my God it works! hahahaha, I really didn't notice that. I still can't believe this is a typo problem. Thank you so much sir you help me a lot! I can't say how grateful I am. I still have 2 problems that related to this case. Can you help me solve it? I really need this to be done soon. Again, Thank you so much Sir! ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image]**Please don't vote.** I know this is not a solution but this will definitely help us in identifying the issue.

This is regarding finding the error in the logcat. May be once *Ricardo F. Seikka*  share the logcat, I can remove this answer.

On Windows (10), this is what I do when the logcat doesn't capture error(what actually happens is the logcat gets cleared when there is an error(only for some errors) and new logcat gets generated hence we cannot see the error in logcat)

@Ricardo F. Seikka (I assume you are using Windows too)

- Launch your app
- before clicking the button run below command in terminal

  "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" logcat -c

(instead of qwerty add your name/ look for adb.exe)this will clear the logcat.
 - after clicking the button, run below command

```
"C:\Users\Dell\qwerty\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" logcat -d > "C:\Users\Dell\qwerty\log.txt"
```

- then open log.txt, search for fatal, next few lines should give you an idea what is the issue.

If you are using any other OS, then search for adb.exe and try my suggestion.

Comment: I couldn't find the adb.exe, and from Local, I don't have android folder on it

Comment: try this, in android studio, tools->android-> SDK Manager.

(on left) Appearance & Behavior->System Settings-> Android SDK .

select Android SDK, on the Top Right 'Android SDK Location', here is where you can find adb.exe 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854238/where-is-adb-exe-in-windows-10-located

Comment: I'm working on windows 7. I can't find the sdk folder, but there's an android folder

Comment: Thank you so much. I just found the adb.exe. Now what should i do about it?

Comment: logcat -d > *.txt ( don't miss the > , because > is the one which redirects logcat to text file).

Comment: when i tried to open the adb.exe, it just close by itself

Comment: with open do you mean, you trying to run it by double clicking on it?

Comment: okay, now there's 'waiting for device' on the adb.exe terminal. what should i do?

Comment: see the answer section, I want you to run the command like that on terminal.

Comment: open your app, run the first command. this will clear the logcat (just to make our job easy in finding the actual issue)
then click the button, app crashes, run the second command ( this will redirect the logcat to that log file),

Comment: any luck? were you able to get the log.txt?

Comment: I can't open the SDK cause it makes my laptop run very slowly. But I already got an answer from Eduardo Herzer. Thank you so much for want to help me on this. I never been got help like this before in this stackoverflow. I'm really grateful. I have another 2 problems related to this case. If you can, please help me solve it. Again, Thank you very much :)

Comment: no problem mate:)Just remember this method. You will find it useful when logcat gets cleared. Put your questions on SO, I am happy to help you (If I can).

Comment: my 2 other problems is the scanner result and the qr code image should be downloadable. But I can't really asking questions in the comment sections right?

Comment: better post on SO, I f I don't know the issue then will not be of any help to you. but there are many developers better than me, who would definitely help you.

Comment: I already post the scanner result issue you can check it, but I can't post the download issue.I think i already on my limit to ask a questions.