# USB Debugging with Chrome only works when Android Studio is open

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, usb-debugging

I've searched everywhere and I can't seem to find an answer to my problem.

I spent about an hour trying to use the "*Remote Devices*" feature for Chrome so I could debug my Javascript Minesweeper game on mobile. For some reason, the "Allow this device to use remote debugging" popup **only** shows when I have Android Studio open.

I'm using a Galaxy Note 8. with Android 9.  It won't let me post images, so I've attached Gyazo links with a screenshot of my `About Device`, panel just in case any of the info there helps solve my problem. Also below is my `chrome://version` info

## Chrome version info

https://i.gyazo.com/10c74d3330e702d618ee5f98eba92bfa.png

## Android Version Info

https://i.gyazo.com/a01843df2dd8cd62f74cfb95f059f1a1.png

## OS Info

https://i.gyazo.com/f9c78ef2d1626615e655b1cebe0a7321.png

Comment: So without Android Studio running, does command line `adb` detect your device? If so, close Chrome, run from command line `adb kill-server` to stop the command line version, and launch Chrome to try remote debugging.

Comment: @MorrisonChang `adb` actually doesn't work at all...

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60689131/edit) your post with what PC OS/version you are using. Also confirm that you can copy files between your phone and the PC. Assuming Windows see: [Where is adb.exe in windows 10 located?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35854238/295004) The short version is that only one `adb` can run at a time, and Chrome has its own.

Comment: Added OS info. I closed all other apps & opened the terminal directly in my Platform Tools folder. `adb` still not found. Tried running `adb.exe` and that didn't work either. I have the `adb` file but for some reason it's still not recognized? @MorrisonChang

Comment: Just want to confirm that you are trying to debug a webapp/website in Chrome for Android? I was able to debug a site on my phone (Galaxy S9 / Android 10 / updated Chrome for Android), On PC, not running Android Studio `adb kill-server`, go to site in Chrome for Android, in PC Chrome `chrome://inspect/#devices`  waited a bit for the "accept" dialog on phone, then in PC Chrome tab android phone & tab to show up, then I hit "inspect".

Comment: @MorrisonChang I'm trying to debug a website. It works no problem with AS open, but only if it's open. If I close Android Studio it actually stops working. Kinda weird!

Comment: @KrisBaillargeon I have the same issue, any progress?