# problem while parsing the package in android godot game

Tags: android, apk, release, godot

I released my first game in Godot 3.2.2.stable for desktop. Now, I am attempting to export it for android.

My phones model is Iris X9, android v5.0.

But when I try starting it on my phone, it displays parsing failure.

I enabled installation from unknown sources, but it doesn't work.

For monitoring the problem, I made another empty project(with a blank scene with Godot's icon) and I exported it to .apk file in release mode. But It shows the same error on my phone.

Thanks for help in advance.

Edit: Then I used another device. But it says file not installed or corrupted.

Edit again: I solved the problem(by redownloading the jarsigner and making another Keystore) But now I am having a problem with pausing. I will open another question for that problem.

Comment: Per documentation: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.2/development/compiling/compiling_for_android.html#application-not-installed where is your `adb logcat`?

Comment: I ran the command but it cant recognize adb.

Comment: Do learn how to use your development environment if you intend to build for Android: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: But I have the adb installed with android studio. I used mygame.keystore as debug.keystore doesn't work in release mode. I used jarsigner from AdoptOpenJDK. What should I do

Comment: Without a clear error message, I'm not sure who can help. See: [Where is adb.exe in windows 10 located?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35854238/295004) If you an build a "hello world" app with the default debug keystore and install cleanly then you know that your keystore is faulty in some way.

Comment: this is the error:Certificate chain not found for: GS.  GS must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain. k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
no manifest.
jar is unsigned.
adb: failed to install C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp/Godot/tmpexport.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl2144862369.tmp/base.apk: Attempt to get length of null array]
Error type 3
Activity class {org.godotengine.fishlife2/com.godot.game.GodotApp} dont exist.