# Android Studio cannot detect installed update if updating SDK outside Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

At my office, to make my each programmer team doesn't have to download new Android SDK update one by one, so I downloaded SDK in another PC and let my team just copy and paste the update from that PC.

But after copy and paste, when i return to Android Studio, it still saying that the update that i already get from the other PC previously still need to be download.
[image: SDK Update Information from Android Studio]

But if i look from Standalone SDK launcher, all the update already updated.
[image: SDK Update Information from Standalone SDK launcher]

What can i do to refresh Android Studio SDK detection?

Update:

- To make my question more clear, I copy the update from another PC and paste to SDK folder in my PC "C:\Users\zemmy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk". The destination SDK folder already in Android Studio Path.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio can download it's own SDK into the studio directory. It's just a setting in AS to switch between your local SDK and the SDK within AS. 
See here: [Android Studio - How to Change Android SDK Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path)

Comment: I have updated my question. The SDK folder that i paste to is the folder where Android Studio SDK path is.

Answer (score 0):

First of all;

Are the SDK locations of the updater == Android Studio's?

If yes, did you remember to reopen Android Studio after the update is completed? I have the same issue some times, but it is solved by restarting. To prevent problems at all, I close Android Studio during updating the SDK. But try to close and reopen.