# Android Studio Won't Launch on Windows 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, windows-10, java-7

I recently got a new machine and Windows 10, which I've never used. I'm going through the process of re-installing all of my app development software, which includes Git, Java 7, and Android Studio.

I was under the impression that everything installed fine, but I can't actually launch the IDE itself. The launcher is fine and I can go through the steps of creating a project, but whenever I click finish, the screen closes and nothing happens.

I wish I could give more details but that's really all that happens.

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Some of my theories:

1) Android Studio doesn't seem to like spaces in path names and gives me warnings when creating projects and installing tools. That seems like a silly issue but it's not impossible I guess. It doesn't like "Program Files" or my username which is my full name, but Windows 10 by default names accounts "FirstName Lastname" and I can't seem to change the username to a string without a space.

2) Android Studio is not detecting Java (7). Perhaps it got the wrong location for the Java SDK since I installed them at the same time? Other people seem to have encountered a similar issue, but I would think that I at least get an error. 
3) It's just some dumb tiny bug and I have to reinstall Android Studio.

Any help is appreciated, I want to get to work.

Answer (score 0):

- Java 7 is outdated. Download the java 8 JDK. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
- Set your java path variables accordingly.[Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)
- Make sure you downloaded and installed the version of android studio
  that included the SDK, if not download it separately. https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads
- Set your path variables accordingly. [Android Studio - How to Change Android SDK Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path)