# Change installation directory Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I installed Android SDK in C:, exists some way to change android studio installation for example to E:?

I dont want to uninstall Android Studio or others stuff and reinstall and move manually Android SDK or some files, someone know a fast way?

Thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is move just the SDK. I copy and paste the SDK file (30GB) and notify to android Studio the new directory.

Open Configure ->  Project Defaults -> Project Structure

Later just search directory with the new sdk location, thats all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (easily) change the installation directory without having to reinstall. You can if you edit all references in registries and dependencies for the installations etc. But that will be more time consuming than reinstalling.

At best what you can do is change the android SDK location which will free up a lot of space on C:. But your executables will still reside on c: untill you reinstall.

For moving the SDK to a different path check options in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path)

Comment: You only have to change one registry entry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Android Studio\Path`