# Android Studio Gradle cannot find Android SDK location

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When trying to import a Cordova Android project into Android Studio, I get the error that Gradle cannot find the Android SDK. Where do I set this? The following error message is displayed:

[image]

Comment: Just import the project again. Do not open the project, use import.

Comment: WIth import it is adding the project but I am unable to build.

Comment: Regardless of any type of project, The configuration of SDK path remains same.
Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path)