# Android Studio Error when building apk file

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have bought a source code from Sellmyapp, I was done editing that source code completely but whenever i try to build an apk file it shows me the following error

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   The SDK directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk' does not exist.

I have installed my Android Sdk in C:\Android\sdk and also set sdk location to C:\Android\sdk but still same problem. My Windows is 64-bit, Android Studio is 64-bit, Operating System is 64-bit but still same problem.

Then I copy android sdk and paste it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk So now it shows this error

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: 
>       C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

So please tell me what to do next.
Thanks

Comment: You need to download the right platform (23). Open the SDK manager within Android Studio and select "Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path