# RUN project Android studio

Tags: java, android

Hi I have a problem in the function of a property 'run' project Android studio
When preparing 'edit configuration'

A flag appears as in the image,
thank you

[image]

Comment: You have not set the SDK path, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path

Comment: tank you for info I downloaded but once it works fine and it appears that it needs to be loaded sdk

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPcUu.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5luQ.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ManXQ.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntetx.png

Comment: You have added photos in the comment explaining upload SDK