# Error:An error occurred configuring project ':app'. > The SDK directory does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

i am importing one project. i am running this on linux. but when i build my project it gives me this error.

**Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> The SDK directory '/home/custom/Documents/Zebra_RFID_Mobile-1.0.2.17/C:\Users\DHXW76\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' does not exist.**
>   Below is my local.properties file

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Mon Sep 11 14:54:05 IST 2017
ndk.dir=/home/custom/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=/home/custom/Android/Sdk
```

I am wondering that how is this error showing c:\users.... path, although i am trying it to run this on linux. 
I have also checked my sdk location, it is perfect. can anybody help me solve this issue?

Comment: have u set sdk location ?

Comment: Change the sdk location https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path

Comment: nope @Kaveesh Kanwal, i haven't set sdk location. It is working fine in all the other projects. only showing this issue in particular imported project.

Comment: You need to goto settings and then set the location of your sdk

Comment: @M.Mavini i do not need to change the sdk location. it is working fine in all other projects. i do not there is sdk problem

Comment: Have you checked your sdk location in "File -> Project Structures ?

Comment: Yes @M.Mavani I have checked it

Comment: Have you done "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart"?

Comment: thanks @M.Mavini that helped.

Comment: :) Always do that on unreasonable bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I'm using Linux.
[Project stucture windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrVXO.png)

How I corrected the error:

1. Need to check SDK Manager. Is the SDK similar to your project?[SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLe4e.png)

2.Checking Gradle.[Gradle Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8rQs.png) [Gradle](https://gradle.org/install/#with-a-package-manager)
The version number in the Project Structure /project and in the `/opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-4.6/` folder should be the same. If the problem persists, update the Gradle.

2.1 We go to the site: https://gradle.org/install/#with-a-package-manager and download the binary version. Download the archive we throw in the folder `/opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-4.6/` and write down its version number in Project Structure /project.

3.Restart the studio.

If the program code shows an incorrect version of Gradle, then an error will appear that is difficult to fix. Try to check all the code or create a new project.

Check Gradle easily by creating a new project. I like this method.