# Error in running git cloned android project

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have cloned an android project from Github and after building it up if I try to run it, it displays this error message.
I have already set the SDK path in local.properties file but still showing this error.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGui0.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - How to Change Android SDK Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path)

Answer (score 0):

Go to

1. File -> project Structure into Project Structure
2. Left -> SDK Location
3. SDK location select Android SDK location

And i recommand to you to invalidate cache and restart (in file menu)