# No SDK on Windows 10 when installing android studio from zip

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I read a bunch of questions here about where to find the Android SDK (on users/username/appdata/local/...)

But no answer helped me understand how to find (or download) the SDK, given I did not install Android Studio via `.exe`, but downloaded the archive (zip), and extracted it.

I tried downloading `sdk tools` and using the extracted path as the location for a SDK, and even all of the folders inside it. AS doesn't recognize it as a valid SDK location.

EDIT:

---

Weird... I downloaded the first choice installation exe on my phone, and copied it to my pc, and near the end of the installation, it prompted me with:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
>   Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform-Tools: archive is not a ZIP archive.
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-28_r06.zip': Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
>   Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 28: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-28_r06.zip': Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?.
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/3534162-studio.sdk-patcher.zip.bak': Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
>   Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package SDK Patch Applier v4: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/3534162-studio.sdk-patcher.zip.bak': Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?.

[image: Then the same text as quoted above]

NEW EDIT:

Now after entering the right path to the SDK on my PC:
C:\Users\idanl\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
The folder exists and looks fine, it has a folder called: "build-tools" inside of it.

This is what I get after trying to install any of the SDKs (Level 27,28):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Follow an installation tutorial. The sdk can basically lay wherever you want it. You just need to have the correct path to it. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path/18409923

Comment: Problem is, like I said in the question, I don't have the sdk anywhere on my computer. @JoeS

Comment: You need to download them as well if you haven't done that before. See here and download the sdk for the system you have: https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads Tell me if it was helpful!

Comment: @JoeS TY for your comments. As for the downloadable content, since I can't download exe files (because of my Forcepoint Endpoint), I can't have the sdk that comes with the IDE installed, and I also don't seem to understand how to use the sdk-tools package as an SDK. Can u elaborate on how to download just the SDK so when I put its path in the settings, the error will disappear?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what happens when you've opened android studio from the zip file?

Comment: You should have run through a setup when you started android studio the first time, did you do that?

Comment: I did, it asked me where the sdk was and didn't install it or put it anywhere.

Comment: You said referring to my comment with the download link, that you couldn't have the sdk that comes with the IDE installed. How did you mean that? In the lower download section there is just the possibility to get sdk-tools ?

Comment: I've lost 8 rep points so far, maybe I'll delete this question and you can help me someplace else? @jle

Comment: No need for that, I don't think there will come much more actually. Answer my above question please. The download section contains sdk files to download, they have no ide installed. Don't download android studio again, but the below listed sdk. Also you might find help in that: https://www.androidcentral.com/installing-android-sdk-windows-mac-and-linux-tutorial

Comment: I'll try that again with the link you added, looks like it will help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Posted it as an answer. In case it helps indeed, I'd be happy if you accepted my answer :)

Comment: @jle Still didn't get it to work, have a look at the last edit please.

Comment: Are you stuck on the setup or can you enter android studio? if not, try to open sdk manager, or open it from your zip file otherwise, and try to install all ask tool, if possible. Or does it return the same error?

Comment: NVM, I guess it's some ssl problem with the sdk download. I hope I'll figure it out on my own.

Comment: Is there some place I can download the platform_tools zip other than the regular AS installation? @jle

Comment: It all happened because my workplace security apps blocked the sdk download.. Sorry for the trouble..

Comment: No problem, hope you could figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always download the sdks separately and bind them into your IDE afterwards. Especially troubles using the .zip can lead to that need.
You can refer to that tutorial to set the sdk up: 
https://www.androidcentral.com/installing-android-sdk-windows-mac-and-linux-tutorial