# React native project stucks on :unimodules-react-native-adapter:generateExpoModulesPackageList

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, mobile-application

It is an expo-eject project and the commands I have used after cloning the project are:

Yarn,
Yarn start,
Yarn android,

And it does not show any error but gets stuck on a same point everytime when I try to run the project.

The project runs fine on the laptops of other teammates, but I am facing this issue.
Here are the versions of the installed tools:
Nodejs 14.17.6,
Expo 4.11.0,
React-native-cli 2.0.1,

I am adding an image that shows where the project gets blocked.

[This is the issue in running project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5779K.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018247/react-native-run-stays-in-idle-state

Comment: @pawan I am facing same issue, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and tried @usama-alaf reply, which consisted of:

- Installing the right SDK for the Android device
- Linking the SDK path under project/android/local.properties

But none of the above worked for me. Digging a little deeper, I found [this Github issue from Willem Horsten](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/13683), where the developer states that there was a `yarn.lock` file on one of his Hard Drives. I'm actually running my development environment on a secondary HD, and I also had a lock file in the root of the drive, but after deleting it, nothing changed.

Here's what actually worked for me. I was running Node v12, and trying to build the project, and trying to check whether the Node version was the culprit, I did this:

1. Deleted my `node_modules`, `yarn.lock`, and all other lock files I could find (for some reason there was also a `package-lock.json` file on the project)
2. Since I'm using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), I switched to Node v15.14.0 (the latest I have installed).
3. Installed the dependencies again with `yarn install`
4. Ran `yarn android`, and the build worked this time.