# How to fix android studio gradle build error?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

last week I have installed intellij 2018.1 in my computer for android programming. after that I have found intellij need android sdk and android studio have sdk tools. I downloaded android studio 1.1 everything was fine but android studio 1.1 is to much old. I have created a project with intellij but android_layout.xml file stuck at "waiting for build to finish". I downloaded android studio 3.1.4 latest final version. But android studio was show same error in intellij. I have reinstalled gradle manually I have tried with command prompt but nothing was changed. anytime android studio show intresting results.
I'll be much thankful if you could help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Google already released an official tools for Android development, that is Android Studio. Once you installing Android Studio you'll be prompted to install Android SDK as well during the process. Follow the flow. And, make sure to use the latest Android Studio available from the site, : https://developer.android.com/studio/

and follow the tutorial from here: https://www.javaworld.com/article/3095406/android/android-studio-for-beginners-part-1-installation-and-setup.html

You can't just use any AS version with any Gradle version that you want. As you already have AS fully setup, there's no need for IntelliJ IDE, at least for now. 
You're getting stuck at "waiting for build to finish" because you're using old verion of Android Studio, that even Instant Run and Cached Build been introduced.

Comment: I am using the latest android studio and sdk tools.

Comment: @AryanAkhani does the error still persist? You didn't even have to uninstall Gradle. It's built in inside AS. And it's the build system for AS.

Comment: I have downloaded gradle build tool and unzipped it into a new folder in windows drive. And then I have choosed my gradle folder in AS settings.

Comment: @AryanAkhani i still have no idea why you gotta separate download it.  So the error still there?

Comment: @AryanAkhani like i told in the answer, do the steps. No dev codes outside AS anymore. And there's no such thing as installing Gradle separately when you're installing AS.

Comment: I have reinstalled AS but android studio will say: error: apply script build.gradle

Comment: Well have you try to create that file from the dir folder? Then resync.

Comment: How can I do? Which file I should download?

Comment: sir, initially you didnt have to download any files. You just need to follow the setup steps. BTW, did you append your JAVA_HOME for the Java SDK properly?

Comment: Yes. First I have install jdk 10 but jdk10 won't work so I have installed jdk 8.